# How to start a windows service as administrator?

Tags: windows-services, tomcat7, privileges, administrator, runas

I'm currently performing a task which requires the use of Apache Tomcat.

When starting up Apache automatically through a windows service, the task fails.

However when I right click command prompt, and select 'Run as Administrator' and start Apache using a bat file, the tasks completes successfully.

This leads me to believe the tomcat service needs to be configured to run as admin.

Could you guide me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the service under a local systems account.

Comment: That works but how to do the same with LocalService account (instead of LocalSystem)? I that possible at all? I tried a trick with app.manifest - that did not helped at all. It looks like that with LocalService account it does not allow to run in admin-mode. :-\